# Get count of each day and status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get count of distinct status count for each date available.
Here is my table:

| RequestDate | TransactionStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25 23:59:54 | 2994 - Payment method selected |
| 2022-01-25 23:59:29 | 3000 - Payment failed |
| 2022-01-25 23:59:05 | 0000 - Payment Processed Successfully |
| 2022-01-25 23:58:15 | 0000 - Payment Processed Successfully |

based on this table, how can I get total number of records under distinct TransactionStatus for each day from RequestDate column?

Expected result will be:

| TransactionStatus | RequestDate | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2994 - Payment method selected | 2022-01-25 | 1 |
| 3000 - Payment failed | 2022-01-25 | 1 |
| 0000 - Payment Processed Successfully | 2022-01-25 | 2 |

I tried

```
select RequestDate,TransactionStatus, Count(*)
from QPayTransactions
group by 1,2
```

but am getting following error;

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: You need to name the columns you want to group by.

Answer (score 3):

You may aggregate by date and status and then take the count:

```sql
SELECT TransactionStatus, CAST(RequestDate AS date) AS RequestDate,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM QPayTransactions
GROUP BY TransactionStatus, CAST(RequestDate AS date);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
select TransactionStatus,CAST(RequestDate AS DATE) RequestDate, Count(*) Count
from QPayTransactions
group by TransactionStatus,CAST(RequestDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: Okay. You are right. SQL Server doesn't support it. Edited.
@TimBiegeleisen